# Configure TCP Port on Nginx Ingress on Azure Kubernetes Cluster (AKS)

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, rabbitmq, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I need to configure a TCP port on my AKS Cluster to allow RabbitMQ to work

I have installed nginx-ingress with helm as follows:

```
kubectl create namespace ingress-basic

helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx

helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    --namespace ingress-basic \
    --set controller.replicaCount=2 \
    --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux
```

I have setup an A record with our DNS provider to point to the public IP of the ingress controller.

I have created a TLS secret (to enable https)

I have created an ingress route with:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rabbit-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - my.domain.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: rabbitmq-cluster
              servicePort: 15672
            path: /(.*)
```

I can navigate to my cluster via the domain name from outside and see the control panel (internally on 15672)  with valid https. So the ingress is up and running, and I can create queues etc... so rabbitmq is working correctly.

However, I can't get the TCP part to work to post to the queues from outside the cluster.

I have edited the yaml of the what I believe is the configmap (azure - cluster - configuration - nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller) for the controller (nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller) via the azure portal interface and added this to the end

```yaml
data:
  '5672': 'default/rabbitmq-cluster:5672'
```

I have then edited they yaml for the service itself via the azure portal and added this to the end

```yaml
  - name: amqp
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5672
```

However, when I try to hit my domain using a test client the request just times out. (The client worked when I used a LoadBalancer and just hit the external IP of the cluster, so I know the client code should work)

Is there another step that I should be doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue here was that helm was configuring so much of my own stuff that I wasn't able to customise too much.

I uninstalled the ingress with helm and changed the ingress creation script to this:

```yaml
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    --namespace ingress-basic \
    --set controller.replicaCount=2 \
    --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set tcp.5672="default/rabbitmq-cluster:5672"
```

Which pre-configures the TCP port forwarding and I don't have to do anything else. I don't know if it effected it, but this seemed to 'break' my SSL implementation, so I upgraded the ingress route creation script from v1beta to v1 and https was working again perfectly.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rabbit-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - my.domain.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: my.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: rabbitmq-cluster
            port:
              number: 15672
```

Comment: @MarkMcGooking Hi Mark can you please help me I am facing similar issue, and I will try your approach to re-install using the helm. But I need to preserve the same External IP for my Ingress C. Service- how I can do it? Because for that IP on Azure they configured reverse proxy to be accessible from outside since AKS cluster is not reachable. Could you please assist me on this?I would try
`helm install nginx-ingress ... --set tcp.9000="default/serviceName:9000`


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66190275/kubernetes-ingress-controller-cannot-tcp-connect-from-outside-virtual-machine

Comment: I have run:
`helm upgrade nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -f internal-ingress.yaml --set tcp.9000="default/frontarena-ads-aks-test:9000"`
but still cannot access my service...

Comment: @MarkMcGooking can you please check on my question and to see if I am doing something wrong? I really checked many aspects and it seems to me they are working.

Comment: @AndreyDonald - I’m no expert on this myself, hence the question. Are you sure your service is accessible on that port? You could try port forwarding to your local machine with kubectl (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) to ensure that everything is working on 9000 to start with. You can go into azure > cluster and look at the config yaml files for everything (and edit them) maybe there is some clue in there?

Comment: Cheers for this that helped me massively. Sorry to hijack but do you know if there is a way I can limit what IP's have access to this port? What I would like to do is make sure only internal services can access the port, while still enabling ports 80 and 443.